# How to split below C# lambda expression into separate methods?

Tags: c#, linq, events, websocket

**Code:**

```
 var manualWebSocketClient = new InstanceBinanceWebSocketClient(client);

 var socketId = binanceWebSocketClient.ConnectToDepthWebSocket("ETHBTC", data =>
    {
 System.Console.WriteLine($"DepthCall: { JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)}");
    });
 manualWebSocketClient.CloseWebSocketInstance(socketId);
```

**Reference link:** https://github.com/glitch100/BinanceDotNet

Comment: Please, explain us, what do you want to achieve? Just declare `System.Console.WriteLine` outside `ConnectToDepthWebSocket` or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a method that satisfies this delegate : `public delegate void BinanceWebSocketMessageHandler<in T>(T data) where T: IWebSocketResponse;`
Which requires an argument type of `IWebSocketResponse` and `void` as return type. So what you need is a method like below :

```
public void MessageHandler(IWebSocketResponse data)
{
....
}
```

And then use it like this :

```
var socketId = binanceWebSocketClient.ConnectToDepthWebSocket("ETHBTC",this.MessageHandler);
```

Comment: (IWebSocketResponse data)